# MySQL concat function to get hyperlink

Tags: php, mysql

can someone help me with what's wrong with this SQL query, there's something wrong with the concat function;

```
    $query=mysql_query ("SELECT CONCAT('<a href="', user_url, '">', display_name, '</a>') 'Autor', FROM wp_posts")
```

[phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) says Message : syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, don't generate links with MySQL. It can be really difficult to troubleshoot, lead to vulnerabilities and create confusion. You're much better off obtaining the data using the `mysql_query` (better yet, use `mysqli`), and then piecing the link together in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the `CONCAT` section:

```
SELECT CONCAT('<a href="', user_url, '">', display_name, '</a>'), Author FROM wp_posts
```

**Edit**

OK, now you've updated the code to include the PHP I can see the problem. You're not escaping the double quotes in your query:

```
$query=mysql_query ("SELECT CONCAT('<a href=\"', user_url, '\">', display_name, '</a>'), Author FROM wp_posts")
```

Incidentally, you [shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

Comment: I tried it and it still gives me the same error. Yes, author shouldn0t be quoted, my mistake.

Comment: There's an extra comma before `FROM` that I didn't notice previously. Removed it now.

Comment: Yes, I already removed the extra comma, but still get the error

Answer (score 1):

The above error, it is a PHP error, not the SQL. So check your PHP syntax. The SQL looks ok.

Try this one:

```
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT CONCAT('<a href="', user_url, '">', display_name, '</a>'), autor FROM wp_posts
SQL;
```

Comment: I have updated the code above. Still not working.

Comment: Just edited the code. You should put more data to your question.